# Apply round off setting to whole notebook

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have too Large data and too small data in form of numpy array . and too many calculations .I dont want to apply `round(num,k)` everywhere. Is there any way to do some global setting to round off everything with 3 decimal places ? I use Ipython notebook .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.randn(5)
Out[2]: array([-0.15421429, -1.3773473 ,  0.89456261, -0.17368004, -0.92570868])

In [3]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

In [4]: np.random.randn(5)
Out[4]: array([-0.497, -1.057, -0.638, -0.566,  0.077])
```

In an IPython session you can also use the `%precision` magic to do the same thing:

```
In [5]: %precision 2
Out[5]: u'%.2f'

In [6]: np.random.randn(5)
Out[6]: array([-1.06,  0.33, -1.8 ,  0.74, -0.73])
```

Note that this **only affects how the numbers are displayed** - behind the scenes, numpy still uses the full floating point precision (~15 decimal digits for `np.double`) in its calculations.

---

It seems the OP was interested in writing the arrays to text files with fewer decimal places of precision, rather than how they were displayed.

One way to write numpy arrays to text files is to use [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). This function takes a `fmt` argument, which allows you to specify any arbitrary string format including the number of decimal places to print.

For example:

```
x = np.random.randn(10)

# this writes the array out to 6 decimal places
np.savetxt('six_dp.txt', x, fmt='.6f')

# this writes the same array to 3 decimal places
np.savetxt('three_dp.txt', x, fmt='.3f')
```

You can read more about how string formatting works in Python [here](http://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/).

Comment: Thanks For reply but my concern is storage only not printing  , I am sorry i forgot to mention it !

Comment: @Hima what exactly do you mean by 'storage'? Do you mean that your arrays are taking up too much system memory, or do you want to write them out to a text file with fewer decimal places of precision?

Comment: Yeah I want to write them to other places like file or arrays with fewer decimal places or precision.

Comment: I`ve just created custom np.arange() function with np.array and both methods don't work